# Renaming files in Linux to date minus one day

Tags: linux, bash, date, rename

I have a procedure (.sh) that extracts data and writes it to .csv files.
The name we use for these .csv files we create based on this statement:

```
for f in $DATA_DIR/*.csv 
do 
      mv $f ${f%.csv}$(date "+__$FROM_DATE""_$FROM_DATE""000000.csv")
      
done
```

Where the $FROM_DATE is the variable when running the shell script. This could be any date we want to extract.
Now I would like to name the file the $FROM_DATE but then the day before.
So the name should be one day prior to the data extracted.
I found this on Google but not sure how to implement this in my existing statement:

```
date -d"20220122 -1 day" +%Y%m%d
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What you ask, is not 100% clear. Please show an example of value of `FROM_DATE`, an example input file name, and the corresponding file name after renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format of `FROM_DATE` is `YYYYMMDD` the `date` command in your first script is useless. It does nothing except echoing what you pass it. And your second `date` command does exactly what you want. So all in all the following should make it:

```sh
y=$(date -d"$FROM_DATE -1 day" +%Y%m%d)
for f in $DATA_DIR/*.csv; do
  mv "$f" "${f%.csv}__${y}_${y}000000.csv"
done
```

Comment: Hi @Renaud Pacalet.
I have a second question. this Export creates multiple .csv files with now the  correct name. If I want to zip all these files using the same naming convention.
I am trying this now but that does not seem to work. Could you help me out to rename the zip file with the same characteristic as the .csv:
zip -j $DATA_DIR/"INF_export__$(date -d "+__$FROM_DATE -1 day"+%Y%m%d"_$FROM_DATE -1 day"+%Y%m%d"000000").zip" /data/genesys/extractmi/*.csv

Comment: StackOverflow questions and answers are not a one-to-one exchange. Others may have similar problems to solve and may find existing questions and answers useful. So questions and answers must be clear, complete, non-ambiguous. Please edit your question and add all information there, including this new zip aspect, show an example of value of `FROM_DATE`, an example input file name, the corresponding file name after renaming, and the name of the zip archive.